# How to install Linux in VMWare so that I can also boot as standalone

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, vmware

I have a Windows 10 machine with 3 disks. One of them is unused and I would like to  install Linux on it. Since I don't have a DVD drive in my notebook I installed Linux on it via VMWare using RAW disk (so VM is using the actual disk instead of a VMDK). I thought I would then be able to configure BIOS to boot my machine using the Linux disk, but it won't boot.

How can I accomplish the same so that I install Linux on my third disk and have it possible to boot as well as run within a VMWare if I need to access both system simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot boot your computer into a virtual machine built using VMware.

For what you ask, you need to install Linux over Windows in dual-boot
configuration. I don't advise this, since this config has many gotchas,
and in addition you will never be able to boot both Windows and Linux
at the same time.

One solution would be to delete the VM, format the third disk by Windows,
and create a Linux VM on it with the disk as a file.
Booting into the VM will always be via Windows, but this is the
simplest solution.

A more complex solution that fulfills all your requirements
is to create the VM as Hyper-V `.vhdx` and use it
either from inside Windows or in dual-boot with Windows.

See the Microsoft article
[Boot to a virtual hard disk: Add a VHDX or VHD to the boot menu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu).

Comment: So what if I installed Linux separately and then create a VM using raw disk with this installation? The same disk should then still be bootable from BIOS, shouldn't it?